# How to skip first column from the CSV file while uploading it into SQL Server using BCP through ruby script

Tags: sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bcp

```
rubyscript.rb

require 'tiny_tds'  
require 'csv'

#For connecting into mssql database
def establish_connection
    @client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'username', password: 'password', host: 
    'hostid', database: 'database_name', azure: false
    puts("Connection secured")
end


#For creating a table
def create_table
        sql = "CREATE TABLE ABBTesting102(first_name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20));"
        @data=@client.execute(sql)
        puts("Table created Successfully")
    end


#For Importing to  mssql using bcp

def bcp_importing
    puts("Inside bcp importing function")
    sql_query = ' 
    BULK INSERT ABBTesting102   
       FROM {students.csv}   
       WITH (FORMATFILE = {format_file.fmt});'

    @datas = @client.execute(sql_query)
    puts("Importing Successfully Completed")
end
```

format_file.fmt

```
14.0  
2  
2       SQLCHAR       0       70       ","      1     first_name         ""  
3       SQLCHAR       0       70       ","      2     email         ""  


Students.csv

       id,first_name,email  
       1,sam,sam@gmail.com
       2,Emma,emma@gmail.com
       3,Max,Max@gmail.com
```

---

This is the sample data. When I tried with this rubyscript, the data is not being inserted. What I'm trying to do is that skip the first column while inserting into the SQL Server using BCP. I tried inserting without using BCP and format file and it seems to be inserting, but I'm trying to insert this `student.csv` while using the BCP. I want to skip the id column while inserting it into SQL Server and I don't want the id to be inserted. The SQL Server credentials given are dummy. Can someone help me insert this CSV into a SQL Server table using BCP while skipping the first column which is the identity column in ruby.

Comment: You could read the CSV and map the array to include only the wanted columns.

Comment: That takes a lot of time, that's why i wanted to do it with bcp.

Comment: The data in the csv is correct, stackoverflow didn't let me post the table so i had to put the table inside the content and that's why the (|) popped up, The csv is separated by (,)

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your CSV (which is in fact a text file), that would help to determine if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: I've edited it, This is how it looks in text file format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any SQL Server to play with at hand, so it's a guess, but your FMT file should look more like this:

```
14.0
3
1       SQLCHAR        0       7       ","     0       id              ""
2       SQLCHAR        0       70      ","     1       first_name      ""
3       SQLCHAR        0       70      "\r\n"  2       email           ""
```

***Note**: The row `Terminator` might be wrong, it could be `"\n"` (UNIX) instead of `"\r\n"` (Windows)*

Let's see the [Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) of this format:

[image]

The `Server column order` seems to do what you want:

> **Server column order**: ...
> ... To prevent a column in the table from receiving any data from the data
> file, set the server column order value to 0.

*What I didn't find out is how to get rid of the header (first line) of your CSV, it doesn't seam possible with `bcp`*